# Matrices that are simultaneously Cauchy matrices and Toeplitz ones

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, toeplitz-matrices, cauchy-matrices

The article
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959190321M
defines "Cauchy-Toeplitz matrices" those matrices that are simultaneously Cauchy matrices and
Toeplitz ones.
Then the author writes that:

> It is easy to check that an arbitrary Cauchy-Toeplitz matrix of order n is of the form
> \begin{equation} T_n = \left( \frac{1}{g +(i-j)h} \right)_{i,j=1,\ldots,n},\label{eq}\end{equation}
> where g and h are some numbers. We assume that $h\ne0$ and the quotient
> $g/h$ is not integer.

I agree that a matrix of the above form is both a Cauchy matrix and a Toeplitz matrix.
However, I have not succeeded in proving that a matrix that is both a Cauchy matrix and a Toeplitz matrix must necessarily have the above form.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  Wikipedia article [Cauchy-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix)
states

> In mathematics, a Cauchy matrix, named after Augustin-Louis Cauchy,
> is an $m\times n$ matrix with elements $a_{ij}$ in the form
> $$ a_{ij}= \frac {1}{x_i-y_j} ;\quad x_{i}-y_{j}\neq 0,\quad
>  1\leq i\leq m,\quad 1\leq j\leq n $$

If the matrix is Toeplitz, then $\,a_{i,j} = b_{i-j}\,$ for some
sequence $\,\{b_i\}.\,$ In particular, this implies that

$$ a_{i,i} = \frac1{x_i-y_i} = b_0,\quad g := \frac1{b_0},
 \quad a_{i+1,i} = \frac1{x_{i+1}-y_i} = b_1. $$

Use these two equations to get

$$   \frac1{b_1} - g = x_{i+1}-x_i,  \quad
 x_i-y_i = g, \quad h := x_1-g. $$

The first differences of the sequence $\,\{x_i\}\,$ is constant
and thus is an arithmetic progression. Furthermore,
$$ y_i = x_i - g, \quad
a_{i,j} = \frac1{(g+h\,i)-(g+h\,j-g)} = \frac1{g +h(i-j)}. $$

Conversely, suppose given a non-constant arithmetic progression
$\,\{x_i\}\,$ and a non-zero constant $\,c.\,$
Define $\, y_i := x_i - c\,$ and $\,b_i := 1/(c + (x_1-x_0)i).\,$ The Toeplitz matrix generated from the sequence $\,\{b_i\}\,$ is
also a Cauchy matrix.

Comment: I think at the beginning you wanted to write $a_{i,j}=b_{i-j}$, otherwise it wouldn't be true that $a_{i+1,i}=b_1$.  
And, towards the end, I agree that $x_i=g+hi$, but I think that $y_j=s+tj$, where $s,t$ are scalars that can be different from $g,h$, so I do not understand why $a_{i,j}$ has the expression you wrote.

Comment: @user222167 Thanks for that comment! I agree with $a_{i,j}=b_{i-j}$. The rest I will respond in my answer.